# Pythonic way of subclassing OpenerDirector

Tags: python

I would like to make a subclass of OpenerDirector. The normal way of getting one is

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler, ...)       - python 2.x
opener = urllib.request.build_opener( ...)        - python 3.x
```

I first tried to use a `__new__` in my subclass by

```
class MyOpener(OpenerDirector):
    def __new__(cls, param1, param2):
        # init myHandler
        opener = build_opener(myHandler)
        # further initialization
        return opener
```

It works but `type(MyOpener(param1, param2))` is `OpenerDirector` and not `MyOpener` ... at least confusing ...

Then I tried to guess what build_opener could do and used a simple `__init__`

```
class MyOpener(OpenerDirector):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        OpenerDirector.__init__()
        # init myHandler
        opener = build_opener(myHandler)
        for h in opener.handlers:
            self.add_handler(h)
        # further initialization
```

It has correct type and seems to work fine, but I'm afraid it is an implementation dependant solution which wouldn't be very nice...

EDIT

In fact, it is not enough to add handlers : the object is not fully initalized and is not usable.

END_EDIT

I know the bulletproof solution would be to have an OpenerDirector attribute in my subclass and simply delegate all OpenerDirector attributes and methods to it (what I would do in c++ or java) but there is a lot of boiler plate code that I would like to avoid in a scripting language.

So the `__new__` solution (first one) would be my prefered one if I could find a way do convert that OpenerDirector object to a MyOpener one, something like `bless` in perl, but I didn't find anything.

Does anyone knows an *explicit casting* in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyOpener(OpenerDirector):
    def __new__(cls, param1, param2):
        # init myHandler
        opener = build_opener(myHandler)
        opener.__class__ = MyOpener
        # further initialization
        return opener
```

Comment: That's what I need ! I suppose that weird things could happen if surclassing like that classes using __SLOTS__, but all seems fine with `OpenerDirector`.